# Should Book-vs-Movie tag be renamed to something more generic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have the tag [book-vs-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-vs-movie).

The usage descriptions says:

> Questions about differences in plot/characters/details between a movie
>   based on a book and the source book, and vice versa.

So it is evidently not fit for questions comparing books and other visual adaptation media such as TV shows. I have seen some questions which seek the comparison between books and TV Shows, so there is some need I suppose.

So how do we go about it?

1. Should we rename the existing tag to something more generic? Like Book-vs-adaptation?
2. Should we create a separate book-vs-show tag?
3. Should we make them synonyms?
4. Should we leave it alone?

Comment: Huh, I just learned that as well as an [tag:adaptations] tag, we also have an [tag:adaptation-comparison] tag. I'm a big fan of the [tag:book-vs-movie] tag ([clearly!](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/book-vs-movie/topusers)), but I smell synonymisation approaching ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor Oh that's a great find. I didn't know those tags existed.

Comment: Another easy fix would be to update the tag wiki to include other things besides movies. The `adaptation-comparison` is probably the most generic that would fit *any* circumstance, but the `book-vs-movie` is more popular. I agree with Rand about synonyms.

Comment: Just to complicate things, the `books` tag that says that it's meant to be used "to differentiate the book from the movie or other media".

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Let's not get into *that* dogfight :-) Media tags have been an issue for *years*: see [2011](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/293/31394), [2013](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3000/31394), [2016](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7893/31394) meta posts about them. Besides, "to differentiate the book from the movie or other media" doesn't necessarily mean the question has to be *about* that differentiation: as Aegon says, the [tag:books] tag could be used on a book-specific HP or LotR question which has nothing to do with [tag:book-vs-movie] differences.

Comment: Can I suggest a wording like `[version-differences]` or `[adaptation-differences]`? We use [\[version-differences\]](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-differences) in a similar fashion on Arqade for this purpose.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The worst part of that tag usage guidance on `books` is that it isn't true. A *maximum* of 25% of the questions tagged `books` could possibly be using it that way, because the other 75% are just using it with `story-identification` where it should be `novel` instead. But  looking at the remaining 25%, a high percentage are still are using it when the only media being discussed is the book.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We already have a broader tag which covers questions comparing books and movies, books and TV shows, comics and movies, or any other set of adaptations of the same work:

### [adaptation-comparison](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaptation-comparison)

> For comparing the adaptations of a work to each other, or comparing a work's adaptations to the source work.

---

### I suggest that we synonymise [book-vs-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-vs-movie) with [adaptation-comparison](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaptation-comparison).

This would mean that [adaptation-comparison](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaptation-comparison) is the master tag, but anyone typing "book-vs-movie" into the tag box would also find and use this tag. If the synonymisation is accompanied by a *merge* (done by a moderator), it will also mean that all currently existing [book-vs-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-vs-movie) questions are automatically retagged with [adaptation-comparison](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaptation-comparison).

(There's also the [adaptations](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaptations) tag, but although *some* of these questions, such as [How is the movie adaptation of R.I.P.D. different from the comic?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/40012/31394), are good candidates for tagging [adaptation-comparison](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaptation-comparison), others such as [Does the Great Ormond Street Hospital control who can make Peter Pan adaptations?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/92486/31394) aren't. So this tag should probably *not* be synonymised, and any necessary retagging done by hand.)

Comment: That seems reasonable. I am all for the making them synonyms.

Comment: @Aegon I'd forgotten about this! Just merged and synonymised the tags, and edited a few of the [tag:adaptations] questions. Not sure what to do about the rest of them, or whether that tag should really even exist.

Comment: Apparently I had too. Thanks Rand! :)

Answer (score 2):

If [adaption-comparison](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaption-comparison) is going to be the master tag, or any other more-generic wording, I think it's important that we think about our usage guidance n combining it with other tags.

Currently, we have these two takes on tagging:

[TV's Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. vs The Comic Books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54654/tvs-marvels-agents-of-s-h-i-e-l-d-vs-the-comic-books)

Which has the tags: [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics)[comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics)[tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv)[agents-of-shield](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agents-of-shield)[adaption-comparison](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaption-comparison).
It's using [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics) vs [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) to specify which versions of the media it's talking about. Similar to the way we do for [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification)

And:

[What are the differences between "The Strain" TV series and the books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67342/what-are-the-differences-between-the-strain-tv-series-and-the-books)

Which only uses [adaption-comparison](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaption-comparison) and [the-strain](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-strain). It specifies which media/versions in the body (and title).

So should we use the media tag + adaptation comparison or not? Whichever we decide, that should be made clear in the excerpt's usage guidance.